# How to load trained xgboost base model parameters into xgboost sklearn API?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

When training and saving an xgboost model in Python using the base API (i.e., xgboost.train(args)), we can then save the parameters using .save_model():

```
import xgboost

model = xgboost.train(args)  # Learning API
model.save_model(args)

loaded_model = xgboost.XGBRegressor()  # Scikit-Learn API
loaded_model.load_model(args)
```

How can we load this trained model into the xgboost sklearn API? My goal is to load a trained xgboost model (trained using the Learning API) into the xgboost Scikit-Learn API as a fitted model, so that I can then leverage other sklearn functions.

The approach I included in the code above does not enable the loaded model to work with other sklearn functions, and I get a NotFittedError when I try to use other sklearn functions on the model.

Here is a link to the Python API for the model I am using: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

I am training the model using the 'Learning API' and trying to load the model into the 'Scikit-Learn API'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used one the standard classifiers or models of `scikit-learn` package, you can save and load your models using `pickle`:

```py
import pickle
 
model.train(X)
saved_model = pickle.dumps(model)
 
# Load the pickled model
loaded_model = pickle.loads(saved_model)
 
# Using the loaded model to predict new data
loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

You can also save the `saved_model` into an arbitrary file and load it afterwards.

```py
import pickle
 
model.train(X)

file_pi = open('model.obj', 'w') 
pickle.dump(model, file_pi)

 
# Load the pickled model
filehandler = open(filename, 'r') 
loaded_model = pickle.load(filehandler)
 
# Using the loaded model to predict new data
loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: @Joekingjoeker Can you please put a link referring to the Xgboox implementation or API?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue I am having is that the model I have trained was trained and saved with the base xgboost API and not with the sklearn API. I am trying to then load the learned parameters from this trained model into the sklearn API.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the xgboost API: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html